# I need a button that performs an action but doesn't trigger validation or refreshes the page(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I need you to recommend me a JSF component that can help in the following scenario(I will first paste an image that will help me explain):
[image]

This page that you see in the image is a registration page, each of the panels have different fields and gadgets, when the register button is clicked, a new user is saved into the database.

The problem i have is in the show buttons. The buttons on top of each panel when clicked should display one panel and hide the other, but they must not trigger the field validation.

I use field validation by the attribute "validator"(in combination with a backing bean method) that most of JSF input fields have. 
Currently everything that you see there is inside one h:form.

-what should i do to display a panel and hide the other without triggering the validation of the panel that is hiding?

-Is there another alternative to the h:commandLink or h:commandButton(they trigger the validation)?

-Putting each panel in a different h:form can do the trick?(Is that permited?)

-What do you think would be the best approach?

Comment: Are the form contents of both panels related to each other? I.e. a real submit must take the data of both panels into a single managed bean?

Comment: No they are different. One belongs to an entity called buyer and another to an entity called Seller. Also i have 2 different managed beans being called in that page. At the moment i managed to do what i want ussing different forms, and using an accordion http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanel.jsf i would like to replace this component with the idea above. The comment that nikki said is ok and it works but i dont want to have that javascript syntax visible in my page. Any ideas?

Comment: If they are different and independent from each other, each **definitely** needs to go in its own `<h:form>`. You should not put everything in single big form. I'm not posting this as an answer because that's already been answered.

Comment: Yes has different forms, as Jitesh said. That is correct now, validation from one panel don't disturb the other. The only thing missing is i don't know how to show and hide the panels when i click on the button. Is there other alternative than what Nikhil Patil said?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. The `<p:tabView>` in combination with (default) ajax magic already does that. Or are you actually not using `<p:tabView>`?

Comment: My apologies i made a mistake. i was not using tabView i was just using 2 p:panel. I will try the p:tabView, i think it will work.

Comment: what software or template you used for this wireframe?

Comment: Mockflow http://mockflow.com/ its nice uh? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use p:tabView Of primefaces, then put your contents(registration panels) in separate tab, use separate form for both of the tab, it will solve your problem....

e.g.

```
 <p:tabView>
        <p:tab title="panel1">
            <h:form id="form1" prependId="false">
                <h:inputText label="Sample Label"/>
                <p:commandButton value="register"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="panel2">
            <h:form id="form2" prependId="false">
                <h:inputText label="Sample Label"/>
                <p:commandButton value="register"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

Comment: This is correct, it is an interesting alternative. It works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> -what should i do to display a panel and hide the other without triggering the validation of the panel that is hiding?

Use two `h:form`

> s there another alternative to the h:commandLink or h:commandButton(they trigger the validation)?

to make POST you must only  use them

I would have used [`rich:modalpanel`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf#) for this purpose

Comment: Thanks that looks good but i cant use richfaces, i already use primefaces and i try to avoid mixing them in one same project, i had conflicts in the past. For my panels i use the p:panel of primefaces. I will try the thing with the 2 forms. And what about refresing the page, could i show and hide the panels with no refresh?(Maybe ajax?)

Comment: I would have used `rerendered `  attribute to rerender , don't know if it is RF specific

Comment: That sounds good how can i set the value of rendered to true when clicked one of the buttons?

Comment: It seems its a feature of RF , [but have a look at it just googled up](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/category/primefaces/page/7/) , if it could help

Answer (score 1):

For the panel's toggle, Why don't you use JavaScript?

```
<h:commandButton value="Show panel 1" onclick="$('#panel1').hide();$('#panel2').show();return false;"/>
```

The **return false** will restrict the page from submitting, hence page won't refresh and since no data is posted back to server, validation phase will never execute.

Bottom line : IMHO this can be handled at client side itself.

Comment: Yes that would probably be the easiest way i think, i will wait a bit more and if i dont find another approach i will use that. Thanks for the code. 1+

Answer (score 0):

You are aware of the immediate attribute, allowing to refresh without changing data.

Unfortunately it doesn't remember changes entered, so you might end up in the validation explicitly being done in your action instead of by JSF itself.

Comment: Can it be done without refreshing maybe? What about the f:ajax component, can it help me? If yes how?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with pulling the validation out. I need it to work just as it does now. To avoid triggering it as i said, what i did was ussing different forms, that worked, but now the problem is to hide and show each form when the buttons on top are clicked.

Comment: Make your question attractive to BalusC - he knows what he talks about and if he answers just do what he suggests.